# Change class of previous selector > child element

Tags: jquery

I have something like below where I want if people click on the ANY of the "***Click here***" text, the [ICON] text change color. I was able to make Click here 1 work, but not 2 and 3. Please help and also tell me why my code doesn't work.

HTML

```
<p class="learnMore"><strong>Click here 1</strong> <span class="red"> [ ICON ]</span></p>

<ul class="expandContainer">
<li>Click here 2</li>
<li>Click here 3</li>
</ul>
```

JS

```
function learnMore(){
  $('.learnMore').click(function(){
  $('.learnMore span').toggleClass('green');  
});  

$('.expandContainer').click(function(){    
$(this).closest('p').find('span').toggleClass('green'); 
}); 
}
```

**Here's the [codepen](https://codepen.io/visibleranking/pen/MRJvro)**

Comment: that's not how closest works, as explained in many many duplicate posts like this. https://api.jquery.com/closest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your selector was wrong. Try it as shown in my sample.
PS: I've also changed the click action to the individual li's. If you want to have the action to work as soon as the whole ul container is being clicked, change it back to:

```
  $('.expandContainer').click(function(){    
      $(this).siblings('p').find('span').toggleClass('green'); 
  });
```

**WORKING SAMPLE:**

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {    
  learnMore(); 
});  

function learnMore(){
  $('.learnMore').click(function(){
      $('.learnMore span').toggleClass('green');  
  });  

  $('.expandContainer li').click(function(){    
      $(this).parent('ul').siblings('p').find('span').toggleClass('green'); 
  });   
   
}
```

```css
.red {color:red}
.green{color:green}


.learnMore {cursor:pointer}
.expandContainer {cursor:pointer; border:1px solid red}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="learnMore">
  <strong>Click here 1</strong> 
  <span class="red"> [ ICON ]</span>  
</p>

<ul class="expandContainer">
<li>Click here 2</li>
<li>Click here 3</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery .closest() method search for ancestors, your code does not work because .expandContainer is not inside p.

Use this:

```
function learnMore(){
  $('.learnMore').click(function(){
    $(this).find('span').toggleClass('green');  
  });  

  $('.expandContainer').click(function(){    
    $('.learnMore').find('span').toggleClass('green'); 
  }); 
}
```